# Firebase : Anonymous authentication - How to set identifier?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

```
const promise = firebase.auth().signInAnonymously();
```

This is the code i use to create anonymous authentication.
I get the name of the visitor and i have to store

```
const user_id = response.uid;
const userPromise = firebase.database().ref('users/' + user_id).set({
                    username: this.state.name
                });
```

response.uid is received from promise.
Again, when the user visits the site again

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
```

I have to grab uid first, i need to use the firebase api to fetch the username.
Is it possible to store username in identifier column?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A good place to store the user name is in the *display name* field of the Firebase Authentication profile. You can read this with `firebase.auth().currentUser.displayName` and [set it through `updateProfile`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User#updateProfile).

Comment: Sir, Do we need to use updateProfile for every auth or can we just pass the displayName in signinAnonymously function?
 `https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#signInAnonymously` -Here i can't find any info about passing arguements in signinAnonymously function

Comment: The Firebase sign-in methods only take the minimal amount of information that is needed to authenticate the user. You'll need to call `updateProfile()` to update the profile.